# requests.exceptions.SSLError

Tags: python

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo en python

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

downloadPath = "descargas"

def new_chrome_browser(headless=True,downloadPath = None):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if headless:
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_argument('mute-audio') #para silenciar

    if downloadPath is not None:
        os.makedirs(downloadPath) #crear carpeta
        prefs= {}
        prefs["profile.default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
        prefs["download.default_directory"] = downloadPath #establecer carpeta descargas
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) #para que no se cierre el navegador
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return browser

def explorar_web(driver,date):
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "fechaBOE").send_keys(date)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "acc").click()
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "puntoXML").click()
    link = driver.current_url
    xml =requests.get(link).content
    with open (f"{date}/boe.xml","wb") as boe:
        boe.write(xml)

def analizar_xml():
    tree = ET.parse("boe.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.iter("item"):
        print(child.iter("urlXml"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 0
    while (x < int(input("introduce el numero de xml del boe que quieres descargar"))):
        driver = new_chrome_browser(False)
        url_base = "https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/"
        date = input("Introuce la fecha ")
        driver.get(url_base)
        explorar_web(driver,date)
        x=x+1
```

Por algun motivo me devuelve este error al ejecutarlo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn   
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 635, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 774, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 459, in ssl_wrap_socket        
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 503, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl  
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request     
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boe.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /diario_boe/xml.php?id=BOE-S-20070519 (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\web python\ArchivosWeb.py", line 52, in <module>
    explorar_web(driver,date)
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\web python\ArchivosWeb.py", line 34, in explorar_web
    xml =requests.get(link).content
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boe.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /diario_boe/xml.php?id=BOE-S-20070519 (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Mi codigo realiza web scraping descargandose el xml del boe de la fecha introducida por parametros un codigo muy basico pero quie requiere de varios imports ademas del driver para gestionar chrome con web scraping el cual esta en mi equipo correctamente, he probado a actualizar la version de python y a importar varios packetes que se recomendaba en algunas paginas web y nada.
Debe ser cosa de mi pc ya que en el pc de mi escuela no tengo este problema y el codigo funciona correctamente, no se si alguien sabra como solucionarlo.
muchas gracias de antemano